# How display return value of one function to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to display return value of arithmetic operation to another  function.

```
function calCaulation(e) {
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first").value);
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second").value);
var z = document.getElementById("oper").value;

switch(z){
    case("+"):
        var a = "Sum:" + ((x + y).toFixed(2));
        break;
    case("-"):
        var a = "Sub:" + ((x - y).toFixed(2));  
    break;
    case("*"):
        var a = "Mul:" + ((x * y).toFixed(2));  
    break;
    case("/"):
        var a = "Div:" + ((x / y).toFixed(2));
    break;
    default:
    var a = "Invalid Operator";
    }
    return a;
    } 
function dispResult  (a) {
document.getElemntById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

when i am trying to do it, the result shows up only once, i want function to be called for every change of input value.

Comment: Than you need to call dispResult every time.

Comment: At the moment, you aren't calling either of the functions so it won't show up at all.

Comment: Please post the HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to grasp exactly what you want from your question, but here is an example I put together which calls different arithmetic functions:

https://jsfiddle.net/n0pchkgr/

```
document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = function(){
    var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('second').value;

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = add(first,second);
    document.getElementById('multipliedOutput').innerHTML = multiplyTwoNumbers(first,second);
};

function add(){
 var returnAmount = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
  returnAmount+= Number(arguments[i]) || 0;   
 }
 return returnAmount;
}

function multiplyTwoNumbers(a,b){
 return a*b;   
}
```